# What is the best approach for adding class and styles without re-render - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a slider and need assistance with the "best" way of implementing the feature. I have a Slider Component which receives children of SliderItems. I clone the children in Slider Component and add props. When the user clicks next or previous button I use a state ***isAnimating*** to determine if the slider is moving and add/remove styles based on ***isAnimating*** state but it was causing a re-render of slider items. I need to add animating class without causing a re-render to the enter slide items. Is there a way to implement such feature?

```
SliderContainer.js

<Slider totalItems={totalItems} itemsInRow={itemsInRow} enableLooping={true} handleSliderMove={handleSliderMove}>                        

{items.map((item) => {            
return <SliderItem key={\`${item.id}\`} data={item}  />;        
})}
</Slider>



Slider.js

const onSliderControlClick = (direction) => {             
const [newIndex, slideOffset] = sliderMove(direction, lowestVisibleIndex, itemsInRow, totalItems);                       

 setisAnimating(true); //Causes rerender
 movePercent.current = slideOffset(); 

setTimeout(() => {                              
ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {                     
 setisAnimating(false);     
 setHasMovedOnce(true);      
setLowestVisibleIndex(newIndex());                
 });             
}, 750);         
};

<div ref={sliderContent} className={`slider-content`} style={getReactAnimationStyle(baseOffset)}>
    React.Children.map(children, (child, i) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, {
    key: child.props.video.id,
    viewportIndex: properties.viewportIndex,
    viewportPosition: properties.viewportPosition,
            })
    );
    })
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `node-sass` library. And make `styles.modules.scss` file for styling, write down css classes. And conditionally you can apply classes on any element like this.

for example -

```
className={props.count > 2 ? classes.abc : classes.xyz}
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to give a better understanding of what I want to achieve.